# How to fix 'indices[1,0] = 66 is not in [0, 25)' error when concatenating two embedding layers in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, concatenation, embedding

I am building a neural network where I have two categorical features that are going through embedding layer each independently and then their embeddings are being unsuccessfully concatenated.

```
x1 = np.random.randint(24, size = (20,1))
x2 = np.random.randint(100, size = (20,1))
X_list = [x1,x2]
label_array = np.random.randint(2,size = (20,1))

input1 = Input(shape=(1,))
output1 = Embedding(input_dim = 25, output_dim = 10)(input1)
output1 = Reshape(target_shape=(10,))(output1)

input2 = Input(shape=(1,))
output2 = Embedding(input_dim = 101, output_dim = 10)(input2)
output2 = Reshape(target_shape=(10,))(output2)

inputs = [input1, input2]
output_embeddings = [ output1, output2]

output_model = Concatenate()(output_embeddings)
output_model = Dense(500, activation='relu')(output_model)
output_model = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(output_model)

model = Model(inputs = input_model, outputs = output_model)
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

model.predict(X_list)
```

When input_dim variables(vocabulary sizes) are equal

> model.predict(X_list) 
>   returns a vector and not error but if input_dim in embedding layer have different sizes like in the example, I get this error:
>   InvalidArgumentError: indices[1,0] = 66 is not in [0, 25)
>        [[{{node embedding_23/embedding_lookup}} = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_23/embeddings/read, embedding_23/Cast, embedding_23/embedding_lookup/axis)]]

My guess is that vocabularies should be the same size, but what to do when they are not?

Comment: For the first embedding set input_dim to vocabulary size of input 1 and for second embedding set input_dim to vocabulary size of input 2.

Comment: Isn't it exactly what I did?

Comment: I've run the above code without any errors. I've modified `model = Model(inputs = input_model, outputs = output_model)` to `model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = output_model)`

Comment: You are right, I mistakenly copy pasted the code and eliminated the mistake